# Intersect on just one column, return others

Tags: sql

I am trying to do an intersection on just one column (map_id), but also return another column (attr):

```
SELECT map_id, attr 
FROM Attr
WHERE attr_id = 0 AND val = '123'
INTERSECT
SELECT map_id, attr
FROM Attr
WHERE attr_id = 20 AND val = '456'
```

However, if the pair map_id and attr don't match, the intersection doesn't work (obviously). How do I do the intersection on map_id, but return the list of attrs? It eventually becomes part of a col In () clause of a larger query.

For example:

```
---------------------------------
Attr_Id    Attr    Val    Map_Id
---------------------------------
0          '1'     '123'    1
0          '2'     '123'    2
10         '3'     '123'    1
10         '4'     '123'    2
20         '5'     '456'    1
20         '6'     '456'    2
30         '7'     '456'    1
30         '8'     '456'    2
```

I want it to return

```
----------------
Attr_Id    Attr   
----------------
0          '1'   
20         '5'
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated it for clarity

Comment: @Kristin in your original query you were using two tables, this one  uses only one table. Is this one correct or was the former?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia i'm using 2, but the issue can be explained more clearly in one. the main issue is that some of the attr_ids are the same, so if we have the list of attr_ids alone, when we go to do a larger query on it, it'll pull in unrelated rows.

Comment: Why is the val column in the expected output blank? Do you want that column returned or just unique instances of attr_id and attr?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia that was an error in my explanation. made another edit that i think makes more sense

Comment: Your query won't return anything if you are intersecting values of ATTR_ID. In your first query you say ATTR_ID should be 0, in the second you say it should be 20. Both are different. They are not the same.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia i fixed the error. there should be a map id - trying to obfuscate the table names and it just ended up messing everything up. the map ids should be intersected, but i really need the unique attrs from it.

Comment: I changed my answer but with your sample data intersecting the map_id values would result in every row of your table meeting the criteria. Both your first query and the 2nd query (that you are intersecting) have rows where MAP_ID is 1 and MAP_ID is 2. Those are the only 2 map_id values on the table so all rows come back.

Comment: It might actually be easier if you show the full query and a few full rows of the table(s) and the output expected on just the sample rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to find the matching attributes for a `map_id` when the `map_id` has both attributes.  There are different ways to approach this query.  Here is one way:

```
select a.attr_id, a.attr
from Attr a
where (attr_id = 0 and val = '123' or
       attr_id = 20 and val = '456'
      ) and
      2 = (select count(distinct a2.attr_id)
           from attr a2
           where a2.map_id = a.map_id and
                (a2.attr_id = 0 and a2.val = '123' or
                 a2.attr_id = 20 and a2.val = '456'
                )
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select a.attr_id, a.attr
  from (select map_id
          from attr
         where attr_id = 0
           and val = '123'
        intersect
        select map_id
          from attr
         where attr_id = 20
           and val = '456') v
  join attr a
    on v.map_id = a.map_id
```

The reason it returns every record is because your 2 queries both produce MAP_ID values of 1 and 2. Thus, every single row of the table with a MAP_ID of 1 or 2 will be returned. This does not match your expected output but matches your explanation.